# ShowModel dialogue box and Dialogue arguments not working in Edge/chrome browsers

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Could you please help me out regarding showing dialogue box issue below is snippet.

ShowModel dialogue box and Dialogue arguments not working in Edge/chrome browsers.

```
showModalDialog(IAllURLs_URL_CASH_DENOMS,window,"status:no;help:no;edge:raised;dialogWidth:800px;dialogHeight:600px;dialogLeft:0;dialogTop:0;center:yes");

   var pContents                                            = dialogArguments;
   var strDenoms                                            = pContents.strDenomValues;//loading the values from main Bank Transaction jsp to Temp.html page
   divisionName                                             = pContents.loginDivision;
   businessDate                                             = pContents.businessDate;
   strCurrCode                                              = pContents.strCurrCode;
   strCurrType                                              = pContents.strCurrType;
   strCurrAmount                                            = pContents.strCurrAmount;
   strDealType                                              = pContents.strDealType;
```

Could anyone help me for any alternative / suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Feature might be deprecated on your browser, Can you check your browser version and verify from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog

Anyways, its no point in using it as most of the browsers do not support.

Alternative:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog

Also can try this package which seems an interesting choice
https://github.com/niutech/showModalDialog